# jquery Validation - trying to Validate Radio and checkbox bottons and use ErrorPlacemant to display Error Below each group

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Newbie here
I am trying to get Radio buttons and checkbox buttons to validate.

Error message should appear under the last it's groups of radio/checkbox

The radio buttons requires a selection
The check buttons Required one selected minimum

--- On the Media, since all have a unique ID I treated it as a group, but am lost on 
addMethod to validate group.

--- Also on errorPlacement what do I do if I don't have an Element ID?

http://jsbin.com/aqekah/14

Mostly OK, but now I get wrong number of InValids in my alert

Comment: I tried "error.prependTo( element() );" but that placed the error message ABOVE the radio group. :(

Comment: Update: I added 2 methods for the Checkboxes, I was hoping to reuse one method, but I had to clone it "require-one" and "require-1"
the other change I did was to get it to display at the bottom of the checkbox trio set, I gave the last Label an ID in each checkbox set and then used it in ErrorPlacement. Am open to suggestions:)

Comment: Update: Radio button, Added a Label ID to each of the last Radio button in each set. Then I use it for Error Placement. 
I think I am done, Am not fully happy with it, So please made suggestion on what I did wrong or was to improve it or making it cleaner. Thanks

Comment: STILL have one problem. 
Wrong number of InValids in my alert. If error in a checlbox set, it counts that set as 3 errors instead of 1. :(((

Answer (score 2):

We had this come up just the other day actually, this is how I resolved it:

```
var validator = $('form#yourID').validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.is(":radio")) {
                element.closest('.rbl').after(error);
                element.closest('.rbl').addClass('error');
            }
            else if (element.is(":checkbox")) {
                element.closest('.cbl').after(error);
                element.closest('.cbl').addClass('error');
            }
            else { // This is the default behavior of the script
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        rules: { ...
```

Where `.rbl` is a `<table>` tag and looks like this with the following css:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rbl">
<tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1"> Radio 1</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label><input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2"> Radio 2</label></td></tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
FORM .rbl
{
    float: left;
}
FORM .rbl TD
{
    padding: 4px 24px 0 0;
}
```

The same can be applied for checkbox lists with a `.cbl`. All other non-radio and checkbox types will use standard error placement.

Hope that helps.